# NodeMCU Lua Websockets secure not working on 2.0 baseline

Tags: ssl, websocket, lua, esp8266, nodemcu

Does anybody know of a solution to this websockets secure issue? It works fine on the 1.5 baseline but not on 2.0. Any ideas where the issue could be and what changed in SSL/TLS from 1.5 to 2.0? 
Thanks guys.

Answer (score -1):

It's likely caused by the same "bug" that plagues the HTTP module: https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware/issues/1707

That thread is long, very long and only after nearly a year we're seeing the light at the end of the tunnel. The quickest potential fix is to bump `MBEDTLS_SSL_MAX_CONTENT_LEN` to 5120 in `app/include/user_mbedtls.h` and build your own firmware.

However, first I would compile a firmware with debug enabled and see if you're getting any of those "bad message length" errors from mbedTLS.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18127157)

Comment: Yeah, you're right - a bit sloppy I was. You picked the right template from Stack Overflow. The answer is now a bit more expressive.